# Error when trying to use PolynomialFeatures in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My code is returning an error when I use PolynomialFeatures:

```
poly1 = PolynomialFeatures(degree=1)
poly3 = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
poly6 = PolynomialFeatures(degree=6)
poly9 = PolynomialFeatures(degree=9)
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1,1)
y_train = y_train.reshape(-1,1)

predictions = []
predict = np.linspace(0,10,100)

x_poly1 = poly1.fit_transform(X_train).reshape(-1,1)
X_train1, X_test1, y_train1, y_test1 = train_test_split(x_poly1, y_train)
linreg1 = LinearRegression().fit(X_train1, y_train1)

x_poly3 = poly3.fit_transform(X_train).reshape(-1,1)
X_train3, X_test3, y_train3, y_test3 = train_test_split(x_poly3, y_train)
linreg3 = LinearRegression().fit(X_train3, y_train3)

x_poly6 = poly6.fit_transform(X_train).reshape(-1,1)
X_train6, X_test6, y_train6, y_test6 = train_test_split(x_poly6, y_train)
linreg6 = LinearRegression().fit(X_train6, y_train6)

x_poly9 = poly9.fit_transform(X_train).reshape(-1,1)
X_train9, X_test9, y_train9, y_test9 = train_test_split(x_poly9, y_train)
linreg9 = LinearRegression().fit(X_train9, y_train9)

predict1 = poly1.fit_transform(predict).reshape(-1,1)
predict3 = poly3.fit_transform(predict).reshape(-1,1)
predict6 = poly6.fit_transform(predict).reshape(-1,1)
predict9 = poly9.fit_transform(predict).reshape(-1,1)

ans1 = linreg1.predict(predict1)
ans3 = linreg3.predict(predict3)
ans6 = linreg6.predict(predict6)
ans9 = linreg9.predict(predict9)

np.concatenate(ans1, ans3, ans6, ans9)
```

or alternatively

```
for i in enumerate([1,3,6,9]):
    poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=i)
    x_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_train).reshape(-1,1)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_poly, y_train)
    linreg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train1, y_train1)
    ans = linreg.predict(poly.fit_transform(predict).reshape(-1,1))


np.concatenate(ans1, ans3, ans6, ans9)
```

In my code, I am trying to append all the values to a list for later use, but I get an error:

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-bca8e3056e3a> in <module>()
     18 
     19 x_poly1 = poly1.fit_transform(X_train).reshape(-1,1)
---> 20 X_train1, X_test1, y_train1, y_test1 = train_test_split(x_poly1, y_train)
     21 linreg1 = LinearRegression().fit(X_train1, y_train1)
     22 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in train_test_split(*arrays, **options)
   1687         test_size = 0.25
   1688 
-> 1689     arrays = indexable(*arrays)
   1690 
   1691     if stratify is not None:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in indexable(*iterables)
    204         else:
    205             result.append(np.array(X))
--> 206     check_consistent_length(*result)
    207     return result
    208 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    179     if len(uniques) > 1:
    180         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 181                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    182 
    183 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [22, 11]
```

What is the reason I am getting this error? I want the end result to be a array with shape (4, 100).
Please ask if clarification is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things that look incorrect but it's hard to tell without a simple example which we can recreate, and the full error message indicating which line is producing it. I can see through that

- You're calling `poly1.fit_transform` 4 times, suspect this is a copy paste error
- `predictions.append(ans1, ans3, ans6, ans9)` should probably be `np.concatenate((ans1, ans3, ans6, ans9), axis=1)`

But you can see from the stack trace that the error is from line 20, the call to `train_test_split`. What it's saying are the lengths of x and y aren't consistent. The reason is the `reshape` you've added to `poly1.fit_transform(X_train)`. In this case, it's taking the output from the transforms which has shape (n,2) - a matrix - and reshaping into (2*n,) - a vector - which is twice as long as the original X_train.

I would recommend learning how to create a `Pipeline` to combine the `PolynomialFeatures` and `LinearRegression` into a single object which you can fit and predict.

i.e. Take a look at [Polynomial interpolation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_polynomial_interpolation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-polynomial-interpolation-py)

```
model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree), LinearRegression())
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

This code should work

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

X_train = np.ones(200)
y_train = np.ones(200)

poly1 = PolynomialFeatures(degree=1)
poly3 = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
poly6 = PolynomialFeatures(degree=6)
poly9 = PolynomialFeatures(degree=9)
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1,1)
y_train = y_train.reshape(-1,1)

predictions = []
predict = np.linspace(0,10,100)

x_poly1 = poly1.fit_transform(X_train)  # removed reshape
X_train1, X_test1, y_train1, y_test1 = train_test_split(x_poly1, y_train)
linreg1 = LinearRegression().fit(X_train1, y_train1)

x_poly3 = poly3.fit_transform(X_train)  # removed reshape
X_train3, X_test3, y_train3, y_test3 = train_test_split(x_poly3, y_train)
linreg3 = LinearRegression().fit(X_train3, y_train3)

x_poly6 = poly6.fit_transform(X_train)  # removed reshape
X_train6, X_test6, y_train6, y_test6 = train_test_split(x_poly6, y_train)
linreg6 = LinearRegression().fit(X_train6, y_train6)

x_poly9 = poly9.fit_transform(X_train)  # removed reshape
X_train9, X_test9, y_train9, y_test9 = train_test_split(x_poly9, y_train)
linreg9 = LinearRegression().fit(X_train9, y_train9) # fixed incorrect X,y

predict1 = poly1.fit_transform(predict.reshape(-1,1))
predict3 = poly3.fit_transform(predict.reshape(-1,1)) # changed poly1 to poly3
predict6 = poly6.fit_transform(predict.reshape(-1,1)) # changed poly1 to poly6
predict9 = poly9.fit_transform(predict.reshape(-1,1)) # changed poly1 to poly9

ans1 = linreg1.predict(predict1)
ans3 = linreg3.predict(predict3)
ans6 = linreg6.predict(predict6)
ans9 = linreg9.predict(predict9)

np.concatenate((ans1, ans3, ans6, ans9), axis=1) # use concatenate
```

And using pipelines it becomes

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
import numpy as np

X = np.ones((20,1))
y = np.ones((20,1))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

def create_model(degree):
    model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree), LinearRegression())
    return model

predictions = []
for degree in [1,3,6,9]:
    model = create_model(degree)
    model.fit(X_train,y_train)
    predicted = model.predict(X_test)
    predictions.append(predicted)

predictions = np.concatenate(predictions, axis=1)
print(predictions.shape)
```

Comment: I understand that I could make a for loop, but I spread the code out to make it easier to see if anything was wrong. If you could help me fix the error that I stated?

Comment: You'll have to post the full stack trace so I can see which line the error is from

Comment: So do you think I should trim the code and do what you said and then you will be able to answer my question? Because I think the root of my question won't be solved by that solution.

Comment: I think the main cause is calling reshape(-1,1) on a matrix turning it into a vector when you fit_transform the poly's

Comment: Also typo `linreg9 = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)` shoudl be `fit(X_train9, y_train9)`

Comment: Thanks, and may I ask what did you do differently?

Comment: I just remove the reshape and fixed the typos. I've just refactored and I'll update with the simple version

Comment: You probably meant model = create_model(degree)

Comment: I still have yet to learn about pipelines but they look cool :-)

Comment: Yeah they're really useful as it significantly simplifies your code and makes it easier to avoid accidents like using test data in your training pipeline.